# highchart: set yaxis max and min with hc_yAxis_multiples(create_axis(

Tags: r, highcharts, r-markdown

I have four graphs that each compare the case counts, deaths, and the proportions between four different diseases over time. I am needing help setting the ymax & ymin **specifically for the proportions series** so that their y axes are all the same & they can be visually comparable. **I need to set the y ticks at [0, 30, 60].** Below is just one code sample of a disease graph since they're all coded the same just with different data frames. This is in R markdown using the Highcharter package. Is there a way to add tickPositions within hc_add_series?

```r
highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(create_axis(naxis = 3, lineWidth = 3, title = list(text = NULL))) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = graph_data$Month) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = graph_data$Value, name = "Cases", type = "area", color = '#50b7aa',yAxis = 0,dataLabels = list(enabled = F)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = graph_data1$Value, name = "Deaths", type = "area", color = '#919191', yAxis = 1,dataLabels = list(enabled = F)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = graph_data2$Proportion, name = "Proportion",  type = "area", color = '#926f97', yAxis = 2)
```

[image: pic of graph associated with code pasted above]

[image: pic of all four graphs side by side]

Comment: Hi @c_marie, You should be able to set `tickPositions` individually for each y-axis. Example in basic Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/on3zy08e/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Comment: @ppotaczek yes, but how would I write that in R?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you with R.